# Prove that there exists a semi-orthogonal $U$ such that $U^TAU=B$, where $A$ and $B$ are positive-definite symmetric matrices.

Tags: functional-analysis, symmetric-groups, orthogonality, change-of-basis

Let there be a semi-orthogonal matrix $U \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ such that $U^TU=I_n$ if $m > n$

If $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ are positive-definite symmetric matrices,

1. How may I prove that there exists a $U$ such that
   $$U^TAU=B \quad ?$$
2. Shall we call $U$ a change-of-basis matrix? i.e. changing the bases from dimension $n$ to $m$? OR Is there a better name to describe the transformation done by $U$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not explained the problem clearly.  My understanding of the problem is this: we are given an $m \times m$ symmetric matrix $A$ and an $n \times n$ symmetric matrix $B$ (with $m > n$); we would like to prove that **there exists** a semi-orthogonal matrix $U$ such that $U^TAU = B$.  Is that correct?

Comment: As far as the terminology goes: $B$ is sometimes called a **compression** of $A$, but I don't know if there's any common term for the matrix $U$.

Comment: this comes down to Sylvester's Law of Inertia. My first impression is that this is always possible if the number of positive eigenvalues of $A$ is at least as large as the count for $B,$ while the number of negative eigenvalues for $A$ is at least as large as that for $B.$ I can see how to make up for any zero eigenvalues of $B$ out of what remains. However, for example if $A$ is positive definite and $B$ is indefinite or negative, it cannot be done. Meanwhile, you should identify the exact book or set of notes you are using.

Comment: Or, more trivially, take $A=0$ to see it's false in general.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom. Yes, that's right. I have edited the post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: @Will The Cauchy interlacing theorem provides a necessary condition on the eigenvalues, but I don’t know if the condition is also sufficient

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, looked it up, I see what you mean. I was ignoring the condition $U^TU = I,$ in which case everything is looser. If these were integer symmetric matrices and $U$ maximal rank and integer elements, we would say that the quadratic form with matrix $A$ represents the one with matrix $B.$

Comment: @Will, thanks for the contribution, I haven't used a book/note for the relation. My question was borne out of many example-cases I have seen.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, thanks for pointing out the *Cauchy interlacing theorem*. I've also looked it up. It gives a good explanation of the relationship.

In that case, as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Cauchy_interlacing_theorem), $U$ would be an orthogonal projection matrix unto the subspace of dimension $n$ (since $m > n$). Also, $B$ is a compression of $A$.